# Как я могу показать вывод цикла на странице?

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/info/')
def info():
    for b in range(5):
        print(b)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Мне нужно чтобы я мог посмотреть вывод этого цикла на странице, если я использую return, то он покажет только одно значение '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в шаблоне делать цикл надо.
делаете html файл в нём:

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
   <h1>{{ i }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

а в коде на Python  следующее:

```
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/info/')
def info():
    render_template('<имя вашего html>')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/info/')
def info():
    value_list = list()
    for b in range(5):
        value_list.append(b)
    return value_list
app.run(debug=True)
```

Здравствуйте! Вы можете попробовать сохранить значения, и передать их на страницу в виде списка. Либо, если вы используете Flask + Jinja - сделать `return range(5)` и уже в шаблоне страницы воспользоваться циклом.